# How to show first 12 digits to asterisk and last 4 as digits

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have `EditText` to enter credit card number. I just want to secure first 12 digits and last 4 digits as normal. There should be spaces in between as well. Like the image below:

[image]

And card numbers should be extractable from the `EditText` ie, if `editText.getText()` should return the whole card number. Please help on this.

Comment: You can try using TextWatcher on EditText and handle this character by character in afterTextChanged() method, by getting number of characters and replacing characters with asterisks, after new character is entered each time.

Comment: if i replace it with an asterisk, is it possible to get the cardnumber using 'getText' method from 'Edittext'

Comment: No.You will have to keep original string in a variable. The answer below will also not allow you to get original string from calling getText.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like that:

```
String text = editText.getText();
String star = "**** **** **** " + text.subString(text.length() - 4);
```